# Unable to connect to VPN through ProtonVPN on Fedora 34

Tags: fedora, vpn

I'm attempting to connect through the GUI obtained from ProtonVPN-website.

Here's the log from network_manager.service

```
manager: (ipv6leakintrf0): new Dummy device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/14)
2021-08-17 11:12:55.678868 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.680066 <info>   audit: op="connection-add" uuid="cdc7c8ae-e78f-48a6-a52e-641e15dcf94e" name="pvpn-ipv6leak-protection" pid=6479 uid=1000 result="success"
2021-08-17 11:12:55.682187 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.683701 <info>   policy: auto-activating connection 'pvpn-ipv6leak-protection' (cdc7c8ae-e78f-48a6-a52e-641e15dcf94e)
2021-08-17 11:12:55.684139 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): Activation: starting connection 'pvpn-ipv6leak-protection' (cdc7c8ae-e78f-48a6-a52e-641e15dcf94e)
2021-08-17 11:12:55.684223 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.684474 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.694026 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.694355 <info>   dhcp4 (ipv6leakintrf0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
2021-08-17 11:12:55.697521 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.715458 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.715667 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.717302 <info>   policy: set 'pvpn-ipv6leak-protection' (ipv6leakintrf0) as default for IPv6 routing and DNS
2021-08-17 11:12:55.717914 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): Activation: successful, device activated.
2021-08-17 11:12:55.729584 <info>   audit: op="connection-add" uuid="3f0b6832-b8a8-448a-8708-1f16a573b3a1" name="ProtonVPN SE-FI#1" pid=4109 uid=1000 result="success"
2021-08-17 11:12:55.760663 <info>   audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="3f0b6832-b8a8-448a-8708-1f16a573b3a1" name="ProtonVPN SE-FI#1" pid=4109 uid=1000 result="success"
2021-08-17 11:12:55.765850 <info>   vpn-connection[0x557ca76d0550,3f0b6832-b8a8-448a-8708-1f16a573b3a1,"ProtonVPN SE-FI#1",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 6508
2021-08-17 11:12:55.772617 <info>   vpn-connection[0x557ca76d0550,3f0b6832-b8a8-448a-8708-1f16a573b3a1,"ProtonVPN SE-FI#1",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
2021-08-17 11:12:55.819688 <error>  vpn-connection[0x557ca76d0550,3f0b6832-b8a8-448a-8708-1f16a573b3a1,"ProtonVPN SE-FI#1",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
2021-08-17 11:12:55.824361 <info>   vpn-connection[0x557ca76d0550,3f0b6832-b8a8-448a-8708-1f16a573b3a1,"ProtonVPN SE-FI#1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
2021-08-17 11:12:55.872141 <info>   audit: op="connection-delete" uuid="3f0b6832-b8a8-448a-8708-1f16a573b3a1" name="ProtonVPN SE-FI#1" pid=4109 uid=1000 result="success"
2021-08-17 11:12:55.939214 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.940029 <info>   audit: op="connection-delete" uuid="cdc7c8ae-e78f-48a6-a52e-641e15dcf94e" name="pvpn-ipv6leak-protection" pid=6519 uid=1000 result="success"
2021-08-17 11:12:55.941285 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'connection-removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.947148 <info>   dhcp4 (ipv6leakintrf0): canceled DHCP transaction
2021-08-17 11:12:55.947179 <info>   dhcp4 (ipv6leakintrf0): state changed unknown -> terminated
2021-08-17 11:12:55.957710 <info>   device (ipv6leakintrf0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'user-requested', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
2021-08-17 11:12:55.958234 <warn>   dns-sd-resolved[06c7c50eee4f29d8]: send-updates SetLinkMulticastDNS@14 failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.resolve1.NoSuchLink: Link 14 not known
```

The line

```
2021-08-17 11:12:55.819688 <error>  vpn-connection[0x557ca76d0550,3f0b6832-b8a8-448a-8708-1f16a573b3a1,"ProtonVPN SE-FI#1",0]: Failed to request VPN secrets #3: No agents were available for this request.
```

Seems to hint towards an authentication issue?

Any ideas? I am able to log in just fine, I have a paid subscription. Attempts to connect through protonvpn-cli produces error:

```
Unable to connect to ProtonVPN: ProtonVPN connection failed due to unknown reason.
```

Comment: NetworkManager can connect to Proton VPN just fine, there's no need to use their client.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't see any quick way of changing country profiles as can be done through their client. Is there a quick way of achieving this without the client?

Comment: I've just imported all the countries I need and use them when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Issue solved by

```
sudo dnf install NetworkManager-openvpn-gnome.x86_64
```